# Problem of understanding clock_gettime

Tags: linux, time, clock, system-calls

I am having difficulties with the different clocks which can be accessed by `clock_gettime`. Especially I am interested in:

- `CLOCK_REALTIME`
- `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`
- `CLOCK_THREAD_COUTIME_ID`

I read the manpage, but it didn't help me very much. I use `clock_gettime` in order to generate timestamps for my profiler when it sends the gathered data via socket. I have noticed the following differences:

- `CLOCK_REALTIME`

The events I receive from my profiler with this clocks are sometimes, in a wrong order. The timestamps start with a higher value, though not very much higher. Often the last messages (those with a higher timestamp) appear first and later the timestamps with a lower value.

- `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`
- `CLOCK_THREAD_COUTIME_ID`

I found no difference on both clocks, though they start with a lesser value and are always correctly ordered.

I cannot explain this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system clock source is probably set to TSC instead of HPET.

On modern multi-core systems in general, HPET is a newer system that is more accurate and consistent, and TSC is an older system that is more performant.

On openSUSE, you can find out what your current clocksource is by

`cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`

To set your clock source to HPET on openSUSE, do

`echo 'hpet' > /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`

Further reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HPET

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Answer (score 2):

- `CLOCK_REALTIME` gives you access to the real time clock, i.e. the one that stores the current date and time.
- `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` gives you access to a clock that never goes back in time, you should probably use this one instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`.
- `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` gives you acces to a clock specific to the current process, giving you the CPU time of the process (time spent by the CPU running that specific process).
- `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` gives you acces to a clock specific to the current thread, giving you the CPU time of the process (time spent by the CPU running that specific thread).

Comment: Can I guess CLOCK_REALTIME is reset? This is the only explanation I have for the wrong order I get with this clock.

Comment: On Linux, CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC are both subject to discontinuities due to system time adjustment, e.g. by ntpd.  Use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW to get a timer that is actually guaranteed not to go backwards in time.

Comment: @BDatRivenhill +1 useful for fixing my negative time elapsed problem