# OpenCV program freezes after several seconds of execution

Tags: image, opencv, timer

I am running a program in C++ with OpenCV that reads a camera image and then does some stuff. The camera operates at 15 FPS if I just let it run as fast as it can. I am trying to use a camera to regulate the FPS to a number of my choosing, like 10 FPS. I am using a timer to do this (a timespec object and a clock_gettime() function call). The clock running by itself works fine, and the camera will run fine by itself, but when I try to grab a frame every 100 ms on my own, the program will run for roughly 3 seconds, and then freeze completely. This is the while loop in my code:

```
/* Start the timer */
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    startBit = ts.tv_nsec;

    /* Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat */
    while (1) {  // main while loop 
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
        endBit = ts.tv_nsec;
        if (endBit-startBit >= 100000000) {     // > 100 ms
            fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", endBit-startBit);
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
            startBit = ts.tv_nsec;      // reset timer

            IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);   // Get one frame
            Mat limage(frame);       // convert IplImage to Mat
            if (!frame) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n");
                getchar();
                break;
            }
            cvWaitKey(90);
        }
    }
```

The program will print to the console the time that has passed. The way it is set up now it should print something close to 100 ms (100000000 ns) all the time. But the console gives a weird number once per second: 18446744072800674356. As I mentioned before, commenting out the camera image code, the timer works fine on its own (it still prints out that huge number, but it will run forever). And if I comment out the timer code, the camera will run at 15 FPS with no problems. However, when I run the code together, it freezes after about 3 seconds. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you put `cvWaitKey(90)` right outside the if statement? (see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/c/highgui/WaitKey)

Comment: No, it behaves the same way with cvWaitKey() inside or outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CLOCK_MONOTONIC instead of CLOCK_REALTIME see [Problem of understanding clock_gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930621/problem-of-understanding-clock-gettime).

Here is my implementation of the task:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <time.h>

int wait(double time) {
    timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = int(time);
    ts.tv_nsec = int(10e+9*time);
    nanosleep(&ts, (struct timespec *)NULL);
}

double getclock() {
    timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec + double(ts.tv_nsec)/10e+9;
}

int main() {
    //cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    cv::VideoCapture capture("video.mp4");

    double fps = 30.0;

    cv::Mat frame;

    while (1) { 
        double const c1 = getclock();
        capture >> frame;
        double const frame_time = getclock()-c1;

        fprintf(stderr, "Got frame in %.4f sec. max FPS: %.2f\n", frame_time, 1/frame_time);

        double const delta = 1.0/fps - frame_time;
        double wait_time = 0;
        if (delta > 0) {
            double const c2 = getclock();
            wait(delta);
            wait_time = getclock()-c2;
            fprintf(stderr, "wait: target %.4fsec. actual %.4f\n", delta, wait_time);
        }

        double const while_time = wait_time + frame_time;
        fprintf(stderr, "Show frame in %.4f sec. FPS: %.2f.\n\n", while_time, 1/while_time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. and the camera still freezes after several iterations. It seems like trying to regulate the camera's FPS on my own will cause it to freeze up. 
Here is the output from the terminal without the wait function (entire if (delta > 0) commented out):
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 149.93
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 150.10
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 150.10
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 149.90
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 150.09
    Got frame in 0.0067 sec. max FPS: 150.19
    Got frame in 0.9067 sec. max FPS: 1.10

Comment: That above will run forever with no problems, and will print out a repeat of that block. With the wait statement in, however, the program will freeze after several iterations, and my output looks like this:
Got frame in 0.9138 sec. max FPS: 1.09
Got frame in 0.0065 sec. max FPS: 153.34
wait: target 0.0601sec. actual 0.0602
Got frame in 0.0001 sec. max FPS: 13717.44
wait: target 0.0666sec. actual 0.9666
Got frame in 0.0001 sec. max FPS: 13854.56
wait: target 0.0666sec. actual 0.9666
Got frame in 0.0001 sec. max FPS: 12242.85
wait: target 0.0666sec. actual 0.0666

Comment: It seems that problem not with capturing frames itself, but with measuring time or more probable with wait function. On what OS did you tried that code? How it freeze? Stop printing messages or print only "Got frame..."?

Comment: It's running on Ubuntu 12.something. When it freezes, it stops print messages entirely, and if I use imshow() then the picture will freeze as well. The printed output in my second comment is directly from the terminal where it froze.